# Using Microsoft Test Manager to create test cases instead of TFS web access

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I use Visual Studio Community edition at the moment. I want to create some test cases in a customer's on-prem TFS and they havn't bought the Test Manager extension. When I open web access I cannot add any test plans, test suites nor test cases.

I installed Microsoft Test Manager 2017 and from there I can create everthing I need and also run the test cases. After creating the test cases I can run them from web access.

I would be glad to buy some license for myself but wouldn't want to bother the customer with buying the Test Manager extension.

Question 1: I can't see what license Test Manager is using at the moment, e.g. could I be using a trial license that would expire and thus the above will stop working?

Question 2: Since the above is working, i.e. I can add test cases without paying for anything, is there a chance Microsoft will be plugging this in a future tfs update, i.e. Test Manager will stop working?

Answer (score 1):

The desktop client for Microsoft Test Manager will be retired and only web access will be able to work with test cases.

If you look at https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/pricing/, you see that VSTS Test Manager is included with a Visual Studio Enterprise license. That's one way of purchasing Test.

Another way is to add the Test package to your account through the Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web#pricing. This will cost you $52 per month.

Comment: Enterprise license is too expensive if all I need at the moment is testing tools and as stated in the question, I don't want to ask the customer to buy an extension to their TFS.

Comment: Then I'm afraid there is no other option. You need to pay to use the testing tools, both on the web or with MTM.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) and Team Foundation Server (TFS) offer both **web-based** and **client-based** solutions for manual testing:

- The Test Center in Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) client is a
  desktop-based manual testing solution, which has traditionally been
  used by testers for their Manual testing needs.
- The Test hub in VSTS and TFS is a web-based manual testing solution,
  which works across all platforms and with all browsers. We have
  invested in Test hub over past two years to provide you better
  experiences across Plan, Author, Execute and Track phases of Manual
  testing.

> Because the **Test hub** is a fully featured Test management solution
>   which works across all platforms and with all browsers, we **recommend**
>   you use the Test hub over Microsoft Test Manager for all your test
>   management requirements. You can use Microsoft Test Manager to test
>   your desktop applications by [launching the Microsoft Test Runner
>   (client) from the Test hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/manual-test/getting-started/run-manual-tests#run-desktop).

This answered your second question `Test Manager will stop working?`  For now, even it's not strongly deprecated by Microsoft, but also not been a recommend test management solution in TFS/VSTS. More details you could refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/manual-test/mtm/guidance-mtm-usage#why-the-test-hub-over-microsoft-test-manager).

For question one, there are no trail license for MTM. You need to have **Test Manager license**. This license will be included in below subscriptions. Otherwise you have to buy this license separately.

> - Visual Studio Enterprise - monthly
> - Visual Studio Enterprise - annual
> - Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN
> - MSDN Platforms
> - Visual Studio Test Professional with MSDN
>
> *Source Link: [pricing](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web#pricing)*

In your case, there's a strong possibility that you have a Visual Studio Enterprise license, so MTM work properly.

Comment: I am using VS Community. At the moment we are using either Chrome Test & Feedback extension or MTM to create test cases. Then we can run them in the TFS test hub, even though we don't have the Test Manager TFS extension.

Comment: Can you tell we where I could buy VS Test Professional with MSDN or similar? As stated in the original question, I don't want to bother the customer with buying a license for their TFS.

Comment: @MathiasR You could either chat with sales or call sales xxx in this price page https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/pricing/#tab-d83539eb2b4c2400472 page. for buying Visual Studio Test Professional. If you are using Visual Studio Community. Did your account have [MSDN platformes](https://www.visualstudio.com/msdn-platforms/)  price?